# R: How to ignore certain value on pmin

Tags: r, data.table

I have this two `data.table`s

```
DT <- data.table(name = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 "850Hz" = c(0,1,1,0),
                 "1800Hz" = c(2,0,2,0),
                 "2100Hz" = c(0,3,0,3),
                 "2600Hz" = c(4,0,0,4))
Info <- data.table(Freq = c("850Hz", "1800Hz", "2100Hz", "2600Hz"), Rng = c(3000, 2000, 1800, 1000))
```

I want to create a new column called 'Range' in DT, proceeding for each row like follows:
If the row contains a number different than 0 in the column "850Hz", then the value 3000 should be considered (according to the association stablished between "850Hz" and 3000 in the `data.table` Info). Then, if there's a non-zero number in the column "1800Hz" it should consider the value 2000 and so on for the other 2 columns. At the end, it should calculate the maximum of all the considered values for that row and write that in the new column 'Range'.
And so on for the rest of the rows.

Someone suggested me to use this piece of code:

```
Info[, {
  DT[, Range := pmax(Range, (get(Freq) != 0) * Rng, na.rm = TRUE)]
  NULL
}, by = Freq]
```

I don't understand how it works but it does the job. My question is, why if I wanted to have the MINIMUM of the considered values for each row instead of the maximum? If I use `pmin`, for this specific example all the values in the column 'Range' will be 0 because it *does* consider the cases where the value is 0 in the columns ("850Hz", etc), and I suppose it multiplies that zero by the respective value. I need to tell it to ignore the zeros in those 4 columns. How to?

---

A possible answer would be to convert all the zeros in those columns into `N/A`'s and then using na.rm = TRUE. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that selective substitution. The amount of columns to be considered (850Hz, 1800Hz, 2100Hz, 2600Hz in this example) *could be smaller than 4*. That's because depending of the data, one or more of those 4 columns could be missing. What I would need is to consider all the columns in DT whose name exists in the vector Info[,Freq]. Then, change all the 0's in those columns only, for `N/A`'s. I've been trying and failing every time.

Comment: Everything would be easier if you decided to work with data like `DT2 = melt(DT, id="name", variable.name="Freq")[value != 0]`, in which case you could `DT2[Info, Rng := i.Rng, on="Freq"]` and then if you really needed to... `cbind( dcast(DT2, name ~ Freq), dcast(DT2, name ~ ., value.var = "Rng", fun = list(min, max))[, name := NULL])`. I'd also suggest reading hadley's tidy data article: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Comment: Works fine, thanks. Just two questions, at this part `i.Rng` is there a way to indirectly make reference the name of that column? i.e. `colnames(Info)[2]`. It doesn't seem to work when I simply put that after `i.` Also, is there a way to get rid of those `_` after 'min' and 'max' in the new columns' names?

Comment: The `i.` part is optional, actually (used for disambiguation in case the merged tables have columns with the same name). You can just write `Rng`. I usually include it just to remind myself that the column is coming from `i` in the `x[i]` merge. Anyway, I've added another way below (the `Info_cols` thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the main data in long format:

```
DT_long = melt(DT, id="name", variable.name="Freq")[value != 0]
```

and maybe add the `Rng` column from `Info`

```
DT_long[Info, Rng := i.Rng, on="Freq"]
# or
Info_cols = setdiff(names(Info), "Freq")
DT_long[Info, (Info_cols) := mget(Info_cols), on="Freq"]
```

To display a summary in wide format, you can use `dcast`:

```
res = cbind( 
  dcast(DT_long, name ~ Freq), 
  dcast(DT_long, name ~ ., value.var = "Rng", fun = list(min, max))[, name := NULL]
)

   name 850Hz 1800Hz 2100Hz 2600Hz Rng_min_. Rng_max_.
1:    1    NA      2     NA      4      1000      2000
2:    2     1     NA      3     NA      1800      3000
3:    3     1      2     NA     NA      2000      3000
4:    4    NA     NA      3      4      1000      1800
```

Unfortunately, I don't know a quick way to get rid of the trailing `_.` in the final two columns; maybe that feature will be added later. There are various workarounds like

```
res = cbind( 
  dcast(DT_long, name ~ Freq), 
  DT_long[, c(Rng = list(min = min(Rng), max = max(Rng))), keyby=name][, name := NULL]
)
```

Comment: I tried to use it in my real code and it didn't work well because DT has character columns:

Comment: I tried to use it in my real code and it didn't work well because DT has character columns:

`Warning message:
In melt.data.table(Towers, id = "TOWERS_ID", variable.name = "Frequency") :
  'measure.vars' [LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, STATE, COUNTY, DISTRICT, 850Hz, 1800Hz, 2100Hz, 2600Hz] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'character'. All measure variables not of type 'character' will be coerced to. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.`

 I'm gonna modify DT in my question so it's similar to my problem.

Comment: Edit: the answer to the last issue is just to do some joining between the desired columns in `DT` and in `res`...